# Nested spans in a paragraph will not wrap on children nodes, only on parents

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, jinja2

I am working on a python program that converts a file of text split into sections, headings, and paragraphs into an HTML file that formats based on the text itself. One of the issues I have run into is that I want to have it so that individual words are highlighted, but when the user mouses over the sentence, it has a border around it. Eventually, I hope it is some tooltip of sorts. The main issue I have run into is that the `span"` will not break to wrap as [shown at this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kovyvili/sdrbaj7y/16/). I have tried every combination of `whitespace` and `display`, yet the problem persists. It worked when I was only using a single `span` per sentence. It also works to get rid of the sentence `span class="sentence"` entirely, but that removes the mouseover stuff.

I am using jinja2 to generate these HTML files. The code to generate each section is:

content.html

```
{%- block content -%}
    {%- for  c in content.children recursive -%}
        {%- if c.type=="heading" -%}
            <button type="button" class="item-heading item-heading-level1" id="{{ c.id }}">
                {{ c.text_content }}
            </button>
        {%- endif -%}
        <div class="doc-content-container" id="{{ c.id }}">
            {%- if c.type=="content" -%}
                <p class="doc-content">
                    {%- include "sentence.html" -%}
                </p>
            {%- endif -%}
            {{ loop(c.children) }}
        </div>
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endblock -%}
```

sentence.html

```
{%- for a in c.text_content -%}
    <span class="sentence"
          data-compound="{{ a.compound }}"
          data-pos="{{ (a.pos*100)|round(1) }}"
          data-neg="{{ (a.neg*100)|round(1) }}"
          data-neu="{{ (a.neu*100)|round(1) }}"
    >
        {%- for w in a.sentence -%}
            {%-if w.type == "PUNCT" -%}{{ w.word }}
            {%- else -%}
                {%- if loop.index > 1 %}{{ ' ' }}{% endif -%}
                {%- if w.use_span -%}
                    <span class="word-tagged" style="background-color: {{ w.color }};">{{ w.word }}</span>
                {%- else -%}
                    {{ w.word }}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    </span>
{%- endfor -%}
```

call_styles.css

```css
.doc-content-container {
    margin: 10px;
    /*border: .5px solid black;*/
}

.sentence {
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.doc-content {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.word-tagged {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In the jinja code, I was having issues with whitespace even after using `{%- -%}`, so I tried putting the addition of the space on the same line as inserting the word. I tried, in python, combining the parts of the sentence where the words were not tagged, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, then removing `display: inline-block;` from the `.sentence` style should fix it.